# Cannot properly set retrofit header in Android

Tags: java, android, postman, retrofit

I've the header that can be seen on the following image properly working in Postman:

[image: Postman image]

But I'm not able to use it properly in Android.

My attempts to replicate that so far have been the following Authorization Bearer part is a @Header("Authorization") String header:

```
Call<GPSData> call = apiService.askGPS("Authorization Bearer: " + value, gpsPost);

Call<GPSData> call = apiService.askGPS("Authorization: Bearer " + value, gpsPost);

Call<GPSData> call = apiService.askGPS("Authorization: Bearer: " + value, gpsPost);
```

But none of them work.

Which is the correct syntax for a header equivalent to the one shown in Postman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't send Authorization as the header value as it handled by retrofit if you use `@Header("Authorization") String value` in the api service call parameter, instead do something like this.

```
Call<GPSData> call = apiService.askGPS("Bearer: " + value, gpsPost);
```